# How to include external source files in maven-jar-plugin

Tags: maven

We are building a jar file from external(to the project) classes.
That works fine but we have not been able to figure out how to also include the external source files. I have tried using the "< includes >" tag but only end up with a manifest file in the final jar when used. I have looked at using the maven-resources-plugin but either I used it wrong or it doesn't work in my case. Here is a copy of our of code:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- <phase>generate-resources</phase> -->
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classesDirectory>${itendant.path}/web/rocket/WEB-INF/classes</classesDirectory>
                        <finalName>${itendant.jar.name}</finalName>
                        <outputDirectory>${itendant.jar.path}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sources? Do you mean external dependencies? These should also be managed with maven, using `mvn deploy:deploy-file` as described on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html , and imported in your pom.xml.

If you really mean external resources, then a proper resources declaration would be:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory> [your folder here] </directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

You can have multiple  tags if you have multiple resource directories, of course. Also note that building anything during `clean` is questionable, as `clean` is not run every build - `package` would be a better option.

Comment: By resources I mean I want to include the external (*.java) java source files and the classes in the jar.

Comment: I tried using resources like your example but it did not include the java source files in the final jar.

Comment: If you're building the JAR during `clean`, it obviously won't pick up anything taken during `process-resources`. Put it at the proper point in the lifecycle.